# Bug in the 0-1 Knapsack code. What is the error in my code?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was solving this problem in geeksforgeeks in the practice part but this code fails somewhere I don't understand

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main() {
//code
int T,N,W;
cin>>T;//The number of test cases
while(T-->0){
    cin>>N>>W;//N for number of items and W for capacity
    int dyna[N+1][W+1] = {{0,0}};//table to store values
    int val[N+1],wt[N+1];//val stores value and wt for weight
    for(int i = 1;i <= N;i++)cin>>val[i];
    for(int i = 1;i <= N;i++)cin>>wt[i];
    for(int i = 0;i <=N;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j <= W;j++){
            if(i==0||j==0)dyna[i][j]=0;
            else if(wt[i]<=W)
                dyna[i][j] = max(dyna[i-1][j],val[i]+dyna[i-1][j-wt[i]]);
            else
                dyna[i][j] = dyna[i-1][j];
        }
    }
    cout<<dyna[N][W]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that "this code fails somewhere"?

Comment: When you have code like`cin>>T;//The number of test cases`, this is nature telling you that `T` needs a more descriptive name.

Comment: `int dyna[N+1][W+1];int val[N+1],wt[N+1];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not runtime variables.  Second, don't post exactly what you post to geekforgeeks.  Take your program, remove the `T` stuff and actually put the test case data in  the program.  We don't care about `T` or `cin`.  Just populate the arrays with the test that fails within the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you have separate N and W lengths, which is redundant as these should always be equal. I think the problem you are observing, though, is with your `else if`. You check if the current weight is less than the number of items, which doesn't really make sense. It should probably be something like `else if(j-wt[i]>=0)`, since you are trying to determine if you can subtract the current weight `wt[i]` from the current sum `j` and get a valid (in bounds) result. I imagine you are getting a segfault or similar because you are trying to access `dyna[i-1][j-wt[i]]` when, for instance, `i` and `j` are 1 and `wt[i]` is 10, as `dyna[0][-9]` is (probably) unalloced memory.